# Какая асимптотическая скорость самая медленная?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

> Какая асимптотическая скорость самая медленная?
> 1 - О(3^n)
> 2 - О(n^3)
> 3 - О(n^2 log_2n)
> 4 - О(2^n)

Я ответил неправильно О(3^n), только я не понимаю, почему я не прав? Нас учили, что нужно исключить все несложные асимптотики и оставить самую сложную

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается , по такой логике самый медленный алгоритм О(3^n) или я неправильно всё понял?

Comment: Как-то странно задан вопрос... Самый медленный *алгоритм* - O(3^n), но у вас же "самая медленная скорость" - может, какое время медленнее всего растет, т.е. как раз самый быстрый алгоритм нужен?

Comment: Это вопрос из теста, на котором меня завалили. Звучит именно так. Слово в слово((

Comment: Такое чувство, будто тест составлен так, чтобы специально завалить проверяемого

Comment: Это не автоматический перевод с английского?..

Answer (score 1):

Вы ответили правильно, вероятно, ошибка была в тесте.
[image: На верхнем скрине отмечен правильный ответ]

[image: На нижнем ответ неверный]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/782437)